# Need trusted and reliable way to test on ios and android devices using selenium ,but dont want to do on actual devices need simulator

Tags: android, ios, selenium, automation, automated-tests

Hi need list of trusted website/app/platform where i can test in a reliable way((should be confident after using the platform)) on ios and android devices using selenium ,dont want to do test on actual physical  devices need simulator for the following reasons firstly with the cost involved and secondly dont want to maintain the OS versions.
I came across this resource but have no idea about any of the listed ones there.
https://www.guru99.com/top-10-cross-browser-testing-tools.html

Comment: Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more

Comment: tools or softwares (paid/licensed)where i can use simulators like sauce labs but reliable and which provided lates ios x aur android versions